# Show fields only on edit laravel backpack

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I want to show certain fields only in edit screen. So In Crud controller I have given addField option like this

```
$this->crud->addField([   // Number
        'name' => 'xyz',
        'label' => 'XYZ',
        'type' => 'number',
    ],'update');
```

By this way, I can see this field only in edit screen, however the changes I make are not saved. If I want to save then I have to mention in

```
protected $fillable = [xyz].
```

If I give it in fillable array,then that field will save but it will displayed for create screen also.

What I want is, in create screen I do not want to show certain fields, only in edit screen I wan to show those fields and on saving, it should be reflected in database.

Answer (score 0):

Check the route in view then decide to show something or not

```
if (\Request::is('edit')) { 
   // show element
}
```